# confused with OpenCV findHomography and warpPerspective

Tags: image, opencv

first of all, sorry for my poor English.I would do my best to express my question.
  I am doing a project including two images alignment. what I do is just detecting the key points, matching those points and estimate the transformation between those two images.
  here is my code:

```
static void target_region_warping( 
Mat IN  template_image,
Mat IN  input_image,
Mat OUT &warped_image,
int IN  method
)
{
    vector<KeyPoint> kpt1, kpt2;
    vector<Point2f> points1, points2;
    Mat desc1, desc2;
    vector<Point2f> points, points_transformed;
    vector<vector<DMatch> > matches1, matches2;
    vector<DMatch> sym_matches, fm_matches;
    Mat im_show;
    float x, y;
    Mat fundemental;

    // To avoid NaN's when best match has zero distance we will use inversed ratio. 
    const float minRatio = 1.0f / 1.5f;

    // match scheme, sift + ransac
    Ptr<xfeatures2d::SIFT> sift = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create( 1000, 3, 0.004, 20 );
    Ptr<flann::IndexParams> indexParams = makePtr<flann::KDTreeIndexParams>(5); // instantiate LSH index parameters
    Ptr<flann::SearchParams> searchParams = makePtr<flann::SearchParams>(50);       // instantiate flann search parameters
    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = makePtr<FlannBasedMatcher>(indexParams, searchParams);

    sift->detectAndCompute( template_image, noArray(), kpt1, desc1 );
    sift->detectAndCompute( input_image, noArray(), kpt2, desc2 );

    // step1: match and remove outliers using ratio
    // KNN match will return 2 nearest matches for each query descriptor
    matcher->knnMatch( desc1, desc2, matches1, 2 );

    // for all matches
    for ( std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>>::iterator matchIterator= matches1.begin(); 
          matchIterator!= matches1.end(); ++matchIterator ) 
    {
        // if 2 NN has been identified
        if (matchIterator->size() > 1) 
        {
            // check distance ratio
            if ( (*matchIterator)[0].distance /
                (*matchIterator)[1].distance > minRatio) 
            {
                matchIterator->clear(); // remove match
            }
        } 
        else { // does not have 2 neighbours
            matchIterator->clear(); // remove match
        }
    }

#ifdef TARGET_SHOW
    drawMatches( template_image, kpt1, input_image, kpt2, matches1, im_show );
    namedWindow( "SIFT matches: image1 -> image2", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "SIFT matches: image1 -> image2", im_show );
#endif

    //step2: image2 -> image1
    matcher->knnMatch( desc2, desc1, matches2, 2 );

    for ( std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>>::iterator matchIterator= matches2.begin();
          matchIterator!= matches2.end(); ++matchIterator ) 
    {
        // if 2 NN has been identified
        if (matchIterator->size() > 1) 
        {
            // check distance ratio
            if ( (*matchIterator)[0].distance/
                (*matchIterator)[1].distance > minRatio) 
            {
                matchIterator->clear(); // remove match
            }
        } 
        else { // does not have 2 neighbours
            matchIterator->clear(); // remove match
        }
    }

    //step3: symmetric matching scheme
    // for all matches image 1 -> image 2
    for ( vector< vector<DMatch> >::const_iterator matchIterator1= matches1.begin();
          matchIterator1!= matches1.end(); ++matchIterator1 ) 
    {
        // ignore deleted matches
        if (matchIterator1->size() < 2)
            continue;
        // for all matches image 2 -> image 1
        for ( std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>>::const_iterator matchIterator2= matches2.begin();
              matchIterator2!= matches2.end(); ++matchIterator2 ) 
        {
            // ignore deleted matches
            if (matchIterator2->size() < 2)
                continue;
            // Match symmetry test
            if ( ( *matchIterator1)[0].queryIdx == ( *matchIterator2 )[0].trainIdx &&
                ( *matchIterator2)[0].queryIdx == ( *matchIterator1 )[0].trainIdx ) 
            {
                // add symmetrical match
                sym_matches.push_back(
                    cv::DMatch( (*matchIterator1)[0].queryIdx,
                    (*matchIterator1)[0].trainIdx,
                    (*matchIterator1)[0].distance));
                break; // next match in image 1 -> image 2
            }
        }
    }

#ifdef TARGET_SHOW
    drawMatches( template_image, kpt1, input_image, kpt2, sym_matches, im_show );
    namedWindow( "SIFT matches: symmetric matching scheme", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "SIFT matches: symmetric matching scheme", im_show );
#endif

    // step4: Identify good matches using RANSAC
    // Return fundemental matrix
    // first, convert keypoints into Point2f
    for ( std::vector<cv::DMatch>::const_iterator it = sym_matches.begin();
          it!= sym_matches.end(); ++it ) 
    {
        // Get the position of left keypoints
        x = kpt1[it->queryIdx].pt.x;
        y = kpt1[it->queryIdx].pt.y;
        points1.push_back( Point2f( x,y ) );

        // Get the position of right keypoints
        x = kpt2[it->trainIdx].pt.x;
        y = kpt2[it->trainIdx].pt.y;
        points2.push_back(cv::Point2f(x,y));
    }

    // Compute F matrix using RANSAC
    std::vector<uchar> inliers(points1.size(),0);

    fundemental = findHomography(
        Mat(points1),
        Mat(points2),
        FM_RANSAC, 
        10, 
        inliers,            
        2000,           
        0.9999 );
    // extract the surviving (inliers) matches
    vector<uchar>::const_iterator itIn= inliers.begin();
    vector<DMatch>::const_iterator itM= sym_matches.begin();
    // for all matches
    for ( ;itIn!= inliers.end(); ++itIn, ++itM) 
    {
        if (*itIn) 
        { // it is a valid match
            fm_matches.push_back(*itM);
        }
    }

#ifdef TARGET_SHOW
    drawMatches( template_image, kpt1, input_image, kpt2, fm_matches, im_show );
    namedWindow( "SIFT matches: RANSAC matching scheme", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "SIFT matches: RANSAC matching scheme", im_show );
#endif

    // step5: warp image 1 to image 2
    cv::warpPerspective( input_image, // input image
        warped_image, // output image
        fundemental, // homography
        input_image.size(),
        cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv::INTER_CUBIC ); // size of output image
}
```

I have some problems on step5 in my codes.That is, the matrix "fundemental" is gotten by estimating the transformation from template_image to input_image. So the correct call method should be

```
// may I sign this "1"
cv::warpPerspective( template_image, // input image
        warped_image, // output image
        fundemental, // homography
        input_image.size(),
        cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv::INTER_CUBIC ); // size of output image
```

rather than

```
// I sign this "2"
cv::warpPerspective( input_image, // input image
        warped_image, // output image
        fundemental, // homography
        input_image.size(),
        cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv::INTER_CUBIC ); // size of output image
```

However, actually when I using absdiff method to test the result like these:

```
// test method "1"
absdiff( warped_image, input_image, diff_image );
// test method "2"
absdiff( warped_image, template_image, diff_image );
```

I amazingly found that the wrong calling method "2" produce a better result, that is the diff_image in "2" have more zero elements that in "1".
I don't know what is wrong, do I have some mistakes in understanding the "findHomograhpy" method? I need some help, thanks!

Comment: `WARP_INVERSE_MAP` means that your input is the inverse, which is exactly the transformation from input to template ;) If you remove WARP_INVERSE_MAP you should see the result that you expected. BUT: if you remove it, your code will be a bit slower because warping is always done in the inverse way, so a matrix inversion will be performed. The flag is to signalize that the user already delivers an inverse to reduce computation needs. You can test that, if you try `warpPerspective(template_image, ... , fundemental.inv(), ... , cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv::INTER_CUBIC)` there should be exp. result

Answer (score 1):

please try both of these versions:

```
cv::warpPerspective( template_image, // input image
    warped_image, // output image
    fundemental, // homography
    input_image.size(), // size of output image
    cv::INTER_CUBIC );  // HERE, INVERSE FLAG IS REMOVED
```

and

```
cv::warpPerspective( template_image, // input image
    warped_image, // output image
    fundemental.inv(), // homography, HERE: INVERTED HOMOGRAPHY AS INPUT
    input_image.size(), // size of output image
    cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv::INTER_CUBIC );
```

The flag `cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP` signalizes the openCV function that already an inverted transformation is delivered.
Image warping is always done inversely because you want to make sure that there is exactly one legal value for each output-image's pixel.

So to warp from source image to destination image, you either provide a homography from source to destination image, which means that openCV will invert that transformation, OR you provide a homography from destination to source and signalize openCV that it is already inverted.

see

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29

> when the flag WARP_INVERSE_MAP is set. Otherwise, the transformation is first inverted with invert() and then put in the formula above instead of M .